# Hardhat: ProviderError: The execution failed due to an exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm deploying contracts with hardhat, but cannot use address type in contracts

```
ProviderError: The execution failed due to an exception.
    at HttpProvider.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:74:19)
    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:188:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

I have tried to increase gas and gasPrice, set optimizer's runs for 1 and 200, increase maxCodeSize in network's chainspec, but it doesn't help.
Problem does not occur on hardhat's local network via `npx hardhat node`. Example of contracts' constructor:

```
constructor(address _feeToSetter) public {
 feeToSetter = _feeToSetter;
}
```

Comment: could u share more info, such as a link to the repo? Try to deploy the contract to localhost and see if its deployable. You might have an issue in how ur entering the args. Make sure you have the address as a string `"0x...."`

**Oh, make sure your account has funds on it**